# Images dissapears in mobile view of wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I faced off with such problem: the web site http://amfibija.lv/, and when it shows mobile layout, images displayed for 2-3 seconds and then dissapeared, instead of it just transparent rectangle with a digit:[image]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It looks like your images are trying to pull a retina version of the image. If you look at the paths to the images while you're in mobile view you will see the following:

```
<img src="http://amfibija.lv/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/model-334739_150-80x80@2x.jpg" alt="Георгий avatar" width="80" height="80">
```

From what I can tell after trying to view the image via the path provided, the image doesn't exist.

I would recommend uploading a retna version of your image to that specific location. That should solve your problem.

If you view the page using chrome and open it using the mobile developer tools, you can see the same results and view the page code to help you see the issue.